# Sinatra image displaying issue

Tags: image, sinatra, haml, thin

Here is parts of my view code (haml):

```
%link{rel:'stylesheet', href:'/screen.css', type:'text/css', media:'screen'}
%img{scr:'/tile.jpg'}
```

The *./public* folder contains files
*screen.css* and *tile.jpg*

Problem is image do not appear on the page. At the same time css file successfully applies

I also tried to put *tile.jpg* into *./public/images* but nothing changed.

Webserver - thin, sinatra app.

Comment: Argh,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder
as it is.
src instead scr

Comment: Don't worry, you have to post at least one stupid question on here or you're not a real SO user (my history is littered with such questions:) Better to fail early! At least you found the problem. Don't let it put you off asking more questions if you need to!

Comment: Thanks for your encouraging comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give the [Sinatra Static Assets gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-static-assets) a try. I've started using it for much the same reason, it means I don't have to remember the HTML attributes quite as much (though still a bit) and it should cut down on typo errors a bit too.